# use web frameworks in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, web-frameworks

I am using Netbeans 6.9.1 in ubuntu 10. I have installed everything in my netbeans, apache, glassfish, c/c++, etc, ...

but I have a problem for using frameworks, if I want to create a web application and user Spring or JSF or struts framework, none of them are enable, and I cant use this option in netbeans, how can I enable the them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem a few days ago. I'm on ubuntu 10.10 and I was using openJDK. I switched to the sun jdk and it solved the problem. I'm not sure why it did but it could help you :)

Comment: thanks, the way that I solve problem : 
I create the project, and then write click on the project, -> properties, then adding the framework from there :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks that the J2EE module isn't enabled.

so try to create a new project and select web application in the menu it will enable that module and then you can choose between frameworks even String or Struts.